# Missing PostGIS functions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, spatial-query

I would need to use PostGIS functions like `ST_Subdivide` or `ST_SquareGrid`; these seem however not to be available on my QGIS 3.20 installation.

Most other `ST_`* functions are there and work as expected.

For example, if I run a query containing `ST_Subdivide` I get the following error message:

`ERROR:  function st_subdivide() does not exist`

The PostGIS version is 3.0.0 and should therefore include these functions:

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
postgis_full_version
POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" 
[EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" 
GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " 
PROJ="6.3.1" 
LIBXML="2.9.4" 
LIBJSON="0.13.1" 
LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" 
WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"
```

This QGIS instance is running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Running instead the following from PGAdmin works like a charm:

```
CREATE TABLE "subdivided" AS
SELECT *, ST_subdivide(a.geom, 200) from output_layer_pgsql as A;
```

Is there anything I am missing and/or I need to install?

Comment: What do you get when you try to use these functions? Any error message?

Comment: Thanks for the hint: I edited the question.

Comment: Which part of QGIS are you referring to ? Since i never heard there were any postgis functions *integrated in* QGIS (maybe *spatialite* functions ...)

Comment: Have you install PostGIS in the `public` schema. Try to call the function qualifying the schema `public.ST_Subdivide` or `myschema.ST_Subdivide`

Comment: Make sure you are passing the correct arguments to the function signatures

Comment: Also, `ST_SquareGrid` is available with Version 3.1.0 and above only!

Comment: And the conclusion is ... ?

Comment: @Snaileater, this was in the DB manager: is there any other place I could run the query in? I will try running it directly in PGAdmin.

Comment: @Snaileater: running the same command from PG admin works seamlessly, that is a viable workaround for me/at the moment!